# Starting to learn calculus, but I'm having difficulty.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I wanted to learn how to do calculus, and want to know how to do this question.

Determine the tangent line to the graph of

$f(x) = -4x^2 + 11x - 2$ at $x = 2$ that is parallel to the line $y= -5x - 1$

From this, I assume that simplified it's $f(2) = -4(4) + 11(2)$ that is parallel to the line $y = -5(2) - 1$

$f(2) = -16 + 22 \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;$               $y = 25-1$

$f(2) = 6 \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;$                       $y = 24$

$f = 3 \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; y = ?$

I wan't to know how to solve this question, I have no clue if I am doing it right or wrong, which is why I came here to understand more.

Comment: First of all $f(2) = 4$, not $6$. And then, you don't really need the other given line for finding the tangent. But still, if you are given the equation of that line to which the tangent is parallel to, then you have the slope of the required tangent ($-5$) and a point on the tangent $(2,4)$. Use [Point-Slope form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Point.E2.80.93slope_form) of the line after that.

Comment: This question as is, is meaningless. Are we to assume $f(x)$ is a $z$ or $y$ coordinate? Either one $f(x)$ in $\Bbb R^3$ is an "extruded parabola" if you will, a surface. The line a plane and the tangent a plane normal to a surface. Should the $z$ be an $x$?

Comment: I edited it, it's supposed to be an x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $y = -5z -1$ lives on the $y-z$ plane and the function $f(x)$ lives and the $x-y$ plane there are no parallel lines.  I assume you meant $y = -5x -1$.

And this is a weird question as there is only *one* tangent line at $x= 2$ and it may or may not be parallel to $y=-5x - 1$.  If it isn't then there is none.

If the lines are parallel they have the same slope.  The slope of $y = -5x -1$ is $-5$.  The slope of the tangent line to the function is $f'(x)$.  So $f'(x) = -5$.  At $x = 2$ does it?  What is $f'(x)$ and what does that equal to if $x = 2$? Is it $-5$.  If so the tangent line will be parallel.  Otherwise it will not.

If it does, then the equation of tangent line is figured out the same as any other line when you are given $(x_0, y_0)$ on the line and the slope $m$.  $(y -y_0) = m(x-x_0)$ of $y = m(x - x_0) + y_0$.  $m = f'(x)$ when $x = 2$ and $(x_0, y_0) = (2, f(2))$ when $x = 2$.

So the equation of the tangent line is $y = f'(2)(x - 2) + f(2)$. and if $f'(2) = -5$ it will be parallel to $y =-5x -1$ and will be $y = -5(x-2) + f(2)$.